# Crate destroy when in trigger and button E pressed

Tags: unity, 2d

There are no errors in the console but I feel like im doing something wrong. The crate is not destroying when I click E.

```
public class CrateDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject crate;

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                Destroy(crate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the crate have a Collider attached to it with "is Trigger" checked? 
"Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody. If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component." - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: Okay I added a trigger collider( I had it in the wrong spot) But when I click E it deletes sometimes. I spam E and it eventually deletes.

Comment: Seems like that is another question, perhaps with this question, you should answer your own question, and explain why the events weren't triggering for others in the future, then start a new one,  I can help you with that one too.

Comment: Do not edit the solution into your question, instead you can post an answer yourself and mark it as accepted.

Comment: "If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens" This is somewhat misleading. [As shown in the matrix at the bottom of this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html), trigger messages are still sent between two colliders with `isTrigger` checked, so long as at least one of them is non-static.

Answer (score 1):

Solved Make sure to have the trigger collider in same game object as the script.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code already works and your problem is solved, the script can be cut down a little bit and become a bit more efficient. Instead of using an `if` statement wrapped in another `if` statement, you can simply combine the two together, as seen below:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player") && (Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.E)))
    {
            Destroy(crate);
    }
}
```